# What characters are invalid in searchtext for the here.com geocoding REST api?

Tags: geocoding, here-api

I can't find any documentation for what characters are invalid in the searchtext url parameter.  Here.com refers all technical questions here, and it seems no one has asked this before.

This url generates an error with a hash:

```
https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=myAppID&app_code=myAppCode&searchtext=16055 Sierra Lakes Pkwy #100,  Fontana, 92336
```

Removing the hash fixes the problem, but I was hoping someone has worked out what is and isn't acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The hash character itself is not a "forbidden" character, it just needs to be properly encoded:

```
16055%20Sierra%20Lakes%20Pkwy%20%23100%2C%20fontana
```

On the contrary the hash symbol may be used to denote a secondary address unit designator as it is frequently used in the US and used in the query above.